# OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 'scope'. Please update. Django Facebook connect

Tags: django, django-facebook

If a django baseg webpage, and I use a django-facebook (Django Facebook by Thierry Schellenbach )
And today I noticed, that there is an Error on login in with facebook, the error message is:

> OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 'scope'.
>   Please update. 
>   FB.provide('',{getLoginStatus:function...signed_request,code'});return
>   a;}}});

And I don't know how to fix it.

(I don't want to download new version, becouse, I made some change with model registration and etc.)

Comment: Find str "perms" usage in the package and refactor to "scope"?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I realized, that it has more problems, like facebook cookie now is not fbs_, than fbsr_

Answer (score 0):

Please chanage all place related to "perms" to "scope". Ex: 
"

```
if (response.session) {
                        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                        if (response.perms) {
```

"

to

"

```
if (response.session) {
                        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                        if (response.scope) {
```

"

Feel free if you have any problem.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved this problem, and also it has had more problems not just this perms to scope, but now it's ok